# Is there any performance gain if I use [this] instead of [=] in lambda functions?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

As I understand, `[=]` copies all variables used within the function body, while `[this]` only copies the `this` pointer. But looking at samples, I see `[=]` is widely used where `[this]` or `[this, foo]` would be enough. Is there any reason (e.g. performance gain) to use `[this]` instead of `[=]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "all reference variables"? Did you mean to talk about `[&]`?

Comment: @Lightness: I think it's a typo and he meant "referenced", anything else wouldn't really make sense.

Comment: @Xeo: Indeed. I'm going to go ahead and change that wording for him.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no performance gain, since as you said, only the variables you actually *use* inside the lambda are copied for `[=]`.<sup>†</sup> It's mostly lazyness on the coder's part and keeping the lambda head concise. If you use new variables, you'll have to expand the capture clause to include those variables, and meh. However, sometimes, you want / have to be explicit, for example when you want to mix by-reference and by-value capture.

---

† Note that currently, the `[=]` (or even `[x]`) in the following snippet will *not* copy the member variables into the lambda, contrary to what you might expect:

```
struct X{
  std::function<void()> f(){
    return [=]{ std::cout << "x: " << x << "\n"; };
  }

  int x;
};
```

Instead, you'll get a copy of `this`. This can cause problems if the lambda outlives the parent object, and to make it behave correctly, you currently need to make a local name inside the body of `f` and capture / use that. This name can either be a reference or a value. I prefer the reference, since it is one less copy (for the reference, the member will be copied only into the lambda, while for the value, the member is first copied to that and then copied into the lambda).<sup>‡</sup>

```
struct X{
  std::function<void()> f(){
    auto& x_ref = x;
    return [=]{ std::cout << "x: " << x_ref << "\n"; };
  }

  int x;
};
```

However, [there is a proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3424.pdf) to make the `[=]` and `[member_name]` capture clause copy the member. If you want a reference, you need to then capture `[this]`.

---

‡ Thanks to [@MooingDuck](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6241401#6241401) for the enlightenment.

Comment: Oh that is very interesting about the member capture - makes sense but isn't something you'd necessarily intuitively spot until you read about it on Stack Overflow. thanks

Comment: Actually the code snippets won't compile because you can't capture `std::cout` by value, right?

Comment: @Seth: `std::cout` is a global object, and you can only capture local ones. :)